# Asp.net core website not running in docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Using visual studio 2017, I created a brand new asp.net core website with everything from the default web application template using .net core 2.1.500 and using docker for windows (stable version) with Windows OS but getting the below error when I click start button on docker (no images or containers created on docker at this point).

[image]

> Debugging Error
>
> Cannot find container to attach, check if the correct container is
>   running or not.

When I right click the docker file and click "Build Docker Image" i get the below images in docker, but then again click the start button and nothing happens.

[image]

Below is the default docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1803 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk-nanoserver-1803 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebsiteApp/WebsiteApp.csproj", "WebsiteApp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebsiteApp/WebsiteApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebsiteApp"
RUN dotnet build "WebsiteApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebsiteApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebsiteApp.dll"]
```

[Full log here on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/v3eTAuY0)

Have also tried switching to Linux container but still same issue.

Saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g9uMxYkPNgI) and I am doing the same thing but not working for me, am I missing something here?

Comment: According to the pastebin log, you did not run a container. You just built an image. At 1:32 in the video, you can see the output `docker run ...`. It is the command to run a container.